# why maven-sonar-plugin doesnot exist?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am facing a similar issue as in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4001
but with maven-sonar-plugin. 
Versions i am using are: 
Jenkins - 1.580.1, SonarQube-plugin in Jenkins -2.1, tried with Sonar 4.0 and SonarQube 4.5.1 but faced same error, sonar-maven-plugin: 2.6 /2.7.1 (tried both) 
I face this error when i use Sonar post build step in my Jenkins configuration and this is frequent issue seen in different jobs
Error is

```
 [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'sonar'.
 [INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin: checking for updates from central
 [INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin: checking for updates from snapshots
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Trace
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1569)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1851)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionNotFoundException: The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:229)
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.DefaultPluginVersionManager.resolvePluginVersion(DefaultPluginVersionManager.java:91)
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:179)
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginDescriptor(DefaultPluginManager.java:1642)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.verifyPlugin(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1540)
     ... 15 more
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
 [INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 16 13:13:35 CET 2015
 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/238M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
 Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
 Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
 Finished: FAILURE
```

why am i facing this error ? is the issue(bug) with Sonarqube plugin in Jenkins?

 for time being to avoid this error i have deleted Sonar post build step and added the sonar analysis step in maven goals for maven 3.0.4

```
 Maven goals :: clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://sonardb.test.com:5555/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar <br>
```

but this is a temporary solution, I would like to use Sonar post build step in my job configuration and not face this error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[SonarQube FAQ](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Theplugin%27org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin%27doesnotexistornovalidversioncouldbefound) recommends the following:

> If you get this error message after launching the maven command line "mvn sonar:sonar" add the "-U" parameter to the command line. Maven will then update its local repository with the latest version of the Sonar Maven plugin.
>
> If adding the "-U" parameter doesn't fix your issue, you've certainly encountered Maven bug MNG-4001. The only known workaround is to delete the org\codehaus\mojo directory in your local Maven repository. Of course, if your local Maven repository is synchronized with a repository manager like Nexus, this operation must be also done on the repository manager side.

Comment: I did try this solution but it worked only for 2 days and later i face the same error.

Comment: Is `your local Maven repository synchronized with a repository manager like Nexus` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply cause you are using the wrong coordinates of the plugin:

'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-sonar-plugin'

The sonar-maven-plugin is not part of Apache Software Foundation.

You will find it here:

http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/

And how to use it here:

http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: I havent mentioned the plugin info(path and version) in pom.xml, but it is picking directly from somewhere, and this is causing the error.
Also is there any  option other than mentioning the plugin info in pom.xml ? as i would consider editing the pom.xml as the last option

Comment: You can call it directly on command via `mvn ... org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:GOAL`...Best is to put it into a pom (pluginManagement) so you can defined default values for execution so you don't need to give them all on command line...

Comment: I have tried this, but the issue with this solution is i am not able to select different jdk version for sonar analysis(i.e.; maven analysis should be done with jdk6 and sonar analysis shd be done with jdk7). If there is a post build step then we can select different jdk version for sonar analysis, but if we use the solution u said( mvn...) how to tell sonar to use jdk 7 ?

Comment: You need to tell Maven to run with a different version which can be done by using Toolchain....